# MVC Add View T4 Get Directory Name

Tags: asp.net-mvc, t4

When adding a view in MVC using the "Add View" dialog, is is possible to get the name of the folder it's being added to from the T4 view template (e.g. "MyController" folder, "Shared" folder, etc.)?

I'm trying to figure out the controller name when adding a view and thought I could determine it using the folder name. We have a naming convention for shared views that makes it easy to determine the controller name but views in a controller folder use the standard naming convention (e.g. "Index", "Details").

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell there is no way to get the path to the file being generated. There is no property on the [MvcTextTemplateHost](http://matt-ward.blogspot.com/2011/10/asp-net-mvc-3-t4-template-properties.html) that provides this.

However it looks like the Namespace property will give you the parent folder. So if your project has a root namespace of Test and you are adding a new view to the Views\Home folder then the Namespace property will return "Test.Views.Home".

```
MvcTextTemplateHost mvcHost = (MvcTextTemplateHost)(Host);
string namespace = mvcHost.Namespace;
```

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this was I wrote a T4 DesignHelper class inside visual Studio I had to add some references in the Visaul Studio ASP.NET MVC Web Project to

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.10.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.TextTemplating.Interfaces.10.0
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Mvc.4.0
System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations
```

maybe some other classes you can break it down in .NET reflector what the mvc host is using. Therefore what you might need.
Then in the first line of the T4 Template I instantiate my T4 DesignHelper class and pass the mvc Host into it. The rest of the methods in the T4 Template are reproduced in the T4Designer class (so I can see whats happening plus whatever other methods I wanted or you might want to add. you can instantiate anything you wish FileInfo db calls use extra reflection to derive info from Model Types and so.
This has a few advantages 1. You can call it from in a controller when a view loads and see what is happening, that all your methods execute and what is going on. Also it reduces the T4 Template to method calls on the instantiated T4 DesignHelper class. And you can put really complicated view generation logic in there.